# How to use sqlite3 in Windows Phone 8 with cocos2d-x project

Tags: windows-8, sqlite, cocos2d-x

I am starting to build a gaming application on windows phone 8.
I am using cocos2d-x game engine
I am developing an game which uses database. 
Can anyone please tell me how to use sqlite in windows phone 8 game. and is there any other way to create DB in windows phone 8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with cocos2d-x but it shouldn't be really relevant if you're trying to use sqlite.

First you need to download [SQLite VSIX package](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html#wp8) for Windows Phone 8. If I'm not mistaken, you already need to be using C++/CX because of cocos2d-x. This should make it easier to use SQLite.

If you need some guidance you could look at [sqlite-net-wp8](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8) and [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) which implement a managed wrapper for it.